# Trying to get SMTP Addresses from all AppointmentItem Recipients

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I iterate all AppointmentItem.Recipients. For each and every Recipient I use the following utility method to retrieve the recipients "normal" SMTP email-adress:

for this i used the posting from stackoverflow: [Getting email address from a Recipient object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391340/getting-email-address-from-a-recipient-object/39394766#comment92470373_39394766)

```
    public static string GetSmtpAddress(Outlook.AddressEntry addressEntry)
    {
        String smtpAddress;

        if (addressEntry.Type == "EX")
        {
            if (addressEntry.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                 || addressEntry.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser user = addressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                smtpAddress = user != null ? user.PrimarySmtpAddress : null;
            }
            else if (addressEntry.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry)
            {
                //returns the actual contact but it has 3 email properties (Email1Address, Email2Address, Email3Address). 
                //How to identify which email has the user selected

                Outlook.ContactItem cont = addressEntry.GetContact();
                String OABID = addressEntry.ID;
                String typ = OABID.Substring(29 * 2, 2);
                if (typ=="00")
                {
                    smtpAddress = cont.Email1Address; <!-- Strange Emailadress
                }else if (typ=="01")
                {
                    smtpAddress = cont.Email1Address;
                } else
                {
                    smtpAddress = cont.Email2Address;
                }
            } else
            {
                smtpAddress = "";
            }
        }
        else if (addressEntry.Type == "SMTP")
        {
            smtpAddress = addressEntry.Address;
        }
        else
        {
            smtpAddress = "";
        }
        return smtpAddress;
    }
```

The Line which is marked with <- Strage Email retrieves a strange looking Email adress: It looks like /o=Exchange xxxxx something xxxx .. At the very end it also containts the smtp adress.

What I am searching for is a 100% robust utility function which retrieves the correct SMTP address no matter what adress typ the recipient is, Exchange User, AddressBook User, or whatever. Any help very much appreciated.

Best regards
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

If the GAL entry no longer exists, all bets are off. Before even touching `Recipient.AddressEntry`, check if the SMTP address is available in the recipient table - use `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` to read the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F"`). If it is not present, read the `PR_ADDRTYPE` property (`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3002001F"`) - this is equivalent to `Type` property on the `AddressEntry` object, which `Recipient` object unfortunately does not expose. If it is "SMTP", just use the `Recipient.Address` property. And only if it is not, use your function above that needs `Recipient.AddressEntry`.

Take a look at the appointment with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, go to the GetRecipientTable tab to check if the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property is available